# How can I use --evolve with train_aux.py in yolov7?

Tags: yolo, yolov7

I am trying to train with yolov7's e6e model using the original data. I want to use "--evolve" to adjust the hyperparameters for training, but I get the following error and it does not work. If anyone has encountered a similar error and was able to solve it, please let me know how to solve it.

command

python train_aux.py --workers 8 --batch-size 128 --data data/original.yaml --cfg cfg/training/yolov7-e6e.yaml --weights yolov7-e6e_training.pt --name v7e6e_evo --hyp data/hyp.scratch.p5.yaml --epochs 10 --device 0,1 --project G:\yolo\result --img-size 256 256 --evolve

error

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "yolov7-main\\train_aux.py", line 682, in \<module\> hyp\[k\] = float(x\[i + 7\] \* v\[i\])  # mutate IndexError: index 28 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 28`

environment

Python version: 3.9.16

PyTorch version: 1.11.0

numpy version: 1.24.3